# e.preventDefault() not doing anything

Tags: javascript, html

My code:

```
if (getCookie('cart') != null) {
    document.write("<button onclick='deleteCartCookie()''>Töm kundvagn</button> <br>");
    document.write("<form onsubmit='testJS()' method='POST' id='orderForm' style='margin-top: 5%;'>");
    document.write("<input type='email' id='mailInput' name='mail' placeholder='mailadress*'>");
    document.write("<button type='mailadress' id='mailB' name='mailBtn'> Beställ </button>");
    document.write("</form>");
}

function testJS(e) {
    alert('test');
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I get the "test" alert so that's working but the problem is that the page refreshes which I thought e.preventDefault would prevent. Can anyone see what I've missed?

Comment: You never passed `e`.

Comment: ^^ That.  Just remove the empty parenthesis from the onsubmit attribute : `onsubmit='testJS'`

Comment: @Archer If i do that it doesn't execute the function at all for some reason :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `event` to the function like:

```
document.write("<form onsubmit='testJS(event)' method='POST' id='orderForm' style='margin-top: 5%;'>");
```